# SF4: Add route within a reusable bundle

Tags: symfony4

I want to create a reusable bundle, e.g. installable with `composer require <bundlename>` and I need to inject some routes into the Router. I could not make it through Annotations nor through RouteLoader. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the old way, creating a config file with yml or xml and put your routes in.

From documentation:

```
<your-bundle>/
├─ AcmeBlogBundle.php
├─ Controller/
├─ README.md
├─ LICENSE
├─ Resources/
│   ├─ config/
│   │  └─ routing.yml
│   ├─ doc/
│   │  └─ index.rst
│   ├─ translations/
│   ├─ views/
│   └─ public/
└─ Tests/
```

See:  https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/best_practices.html#directory-structure

Comment: And where do I include my routes.yml from ? The routes have to install automatically by the composer. I tried, doesn't work.

Comment: You have to use flex for this